# Constructor property of an object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I came across this example while reading the prototype.

```
function Animal(){
    this.name = 'Animal'
}

var animal1 = new Animal();

function Rabbit(){
    this.canEat = true;
}

Rabbit.prototype = new Animal();

var r = new Rabbit();

console.log(r.constructor)
```

And the console is giving me Animal as the output for r.constructor, which is a little confusing as the constructor property should have returned Rabbit as r is created by invoking Rabbit with the new operator.

Also, if I invoke the Rabbit function before assigning the prototype it gives me the desired result.

Comment: You would have to do `Rabbit.prototype.constructor=Rabbit;` before making object

Comment: When you assign the prototype, you changed the constructor to the constructor inherited from `Animal`.

Comment: Why so? Is constructor the property of prototype or the object?

Comment: `constructor` is inherited from the prototype.

Comment: Do you now understand why `r.constructor` returns `Animal` ?

Comment: Yes, thanks to the detailed answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects inherit `constructor` from their prototype (typically); they get their prototype from the `prototype` property of the constructor function that creates them when they're created (if they're created by a constructor function). `Rabbit.prototype`'s `constructor` is incorrect, because of this:

```
Rabbit.prototype = new Animal();
```

That calls `Animal` to create a new instance, and assigns that instance as `Rabbit.prototype`. So its `constructor`, inherited from `Animal.prototype`, is `Animal`. You've *replaced* the default object that used to be on `Rabbit.prototype` (which had `constructor` set to `Rabbit`).

In general, that `Rabbit.prototype = new Animal()` is not the best way to set up inheritance. Instead, you do it like this:

```
Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit;
```

and then in `Rabbit`:

```
function Rabbit() {
    Animal.call(this);    // ***
    this.name = "Rabbit"; // Presumably we want to change Animal's deafult
    this.canEat = true;
}
```

Three changes there:

1. We don't call `Animal` when setting up the inheritance, we just create a new object that uses `Animal.prototype` as its prototype, and put that on `Rabbit.prototype`.
2. We set `constructor` on the new object we've assigned to `Rabbit.prototype`.
3. We **do** call `Animal` when initializing the instance (in `Rabbit`).

Live Example:

```js
function Animal(){
    this.name = 'Animal'
}

var animal1 = new Animal();

function Rabbit() {
    Animal.call(this);    // ***
    this.name = "Rabbit"; // Presumably we want to change Animal's deafult
    this.canEat = true;
}

Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit;


var r = new Rabbit();
console.log(r.constructor);
```

---

Or, of course, use ES2015+ `class` syntax, which handles this plumbing for you (along with a few other benefits).

```js
class Animal {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "Animal";
    }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = "Rabbit";
        this.canEat = true;
    }
}

const r = new Rabbit();
console.log(r.constructor);
```